# How to redirect to cms page after login using an ajax login / register module?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, ajax, redirect

I am using Magento 1.9 on localhost with wamp. I am using an ajax login and register module which redirects to customer account. The login and register are on the homepage. I am trying to redirect to a custom cms page after login, or after registering. I've contacted the developper but so far no replies, so I thought I would try here.

The template file which is used for the homepage, for login forms and register forms looks like this:

```
<?php // If user is not logged in ?>
<?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() != true) : ?>

<div class="account-login">
<!-- login form here -->
</div>

<div class="account-register">
<!-- register form here -->
</div>

<?php /* else if the user is logged in */ 
else :

// redirect to http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page/

endif; ?>
```

so far I've tried:

```
<?php /* else if the user is logged in */ 
else :
$url="http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page";
$this->_redirectUrl($url);
endif; ?>
```

That gave me the following error in  Magento:

```
Invalid method Youama_Ajaxlogin_Block_Ajaxlogin::_redirectUrl(Array
(
    [0] => http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page
)
)
```

note: `$this->_redirectUrl($url);` and `$this->_redirect($url);` gave the same error message.

I tried another way:

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page";
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url)->sendResponse();
```

That gave an error in Firefox saying that there is a redirect loop problem. Another try was:

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page";
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
```

That also  gave an error in Firefox saying that there is a redirect loop problem

I've read that there are ways to redirect to external links wich should specifically be used for that, and then other methods of redirecting. I believe I should edit the module controller to make the redirection work.

The ajax login module controller ( AccountController.php ) looks like this :

```
class Youama_Ajaxlogin_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController

{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_url;

    /**
     * Before actions.
     * @return Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action|void
     */
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        $this->_url = Mage::getBaseUrl() . '?yregister';

        parent::preDispatch();
    }

    /**
     * Disable login action.
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $this->_setLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Disable create action.
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        $this->_setLocation();
    }

    /**
     * Redirect to home.
     */
    protected function _setLocation()
    {
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_url);
    }
}
```

I believe I have to add or change some lines of code there in order to be able to use `$this->_redirectUrl($url);` or `$this->_redirect($url);`

Any help would really be appreciated at this point, I'd love to understand how this works.

Comment: Thanks to  @Amit Bera and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769656/magento-redirect-to-login-page-while-user-not-login-on-landing : I had to put `<?php if($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){ Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('landing-page'));
} ?>` **outside the ajaxlogin.phtml template file of the module** , it works in header.phtml for example. Not sure if that is the cleanest/best solution though.

Comment: Try this extension https://magecomp.com/magento-mobile-login.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change:

```
$url="http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page";
```

to

```
$url=Mage::getUrl('landing-page');
```

if using then try

```
$this->_redirect($url)
```

to 
**EDIT:** `First of all _redirect is not a block class function,it is a controller function`.You need direction then used the code

```
$url=Mage::getUrl('landing-page');

Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url); 
exit();
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work. The error message still says: "Invalid method Youama_Ajaxlogin_Block_Ajaxlogin::_redirect(Array
(
    [0] => http://127.0.0.1/website/landing-page/
)

Comment: are you put this code in block  file...???

Comment: then put block file code...

Comment: the .php file inside module Block folder is community/Youama/Block/Ajaxlogin.php and contains : `class Youama_Ajaxlogin_Block_Ajaxlogin extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Retrieve string 1 if Redirection to profile is YES on system config page.
     * @return string
     */
    public function isRedirectToProfile()
    {
        if (Mage::getStoreConfig('youamaajaxlogin/settings/redirection')) {
            return '1';
        }

        return '0';
    }
}`

Comment: from block you want to redirect to cms pahe??

Comment: thank you you put me on the right path : I had to put the following code inside header.phtml block... not inside ajaxlogin.phtml it would not work , code is working (only in header.phtml) now :`<?php if($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){ Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('landing-page')); }
?>`